# Can a function which is multiplied by "e" have a maximum?

Tags: functions

Short question,

Lets say I have a function $f(x,y,z) = e^x * (\ldots)$. So, no matter what is written in the brackets, the function won't ever have a maximum point, right? Or are there certain exclusions?

Comment: $f(x)=e^{-x-x^2}$?

Comment: Have you heard of indicator functions? They're easy ways to chop off functions.

Comment: It is not at all clear why you think this is true.  It's not.

Comment: $f(x) = e^{x\cdot 0}$ has a maximum. Just sayin'.

Comment: It can easily have a local maximum. For example $x^2e^x$ has a maximum at $x=-2$.

Comment: But I meant multiplied by a positive e^x, not the examples that you guys showed me. The only I look is the term in the brackets, which should be multiplied by e^x and not anything else

Comment: @Maxim It would be helpful if you could add to the question making clear exactly what your conditions are. Why do you rule out $x^2e^x$?

Comment: $e^x \cdot e^{-x} = 1$ has a global maximum and minimum of $1$.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of exceptions. Anything constantly negative will give easy counterexamples, but looking at those functions you might end up thinking (at least when you got the idea you present in the question) that they'll never have a minimum. But anything that eventually goes to $0$ faster that $e^{-x}$  will give a result that eventually goes to 0, leaving plenty of room for a maximum. An example could be $e^{-2|x|}$, multiplying that onto $e^x$ gives $e^{x-2|x|}$ that has a maximum at $0$.